# Highly nested bioinformatics processing

Tags: performance, beginner, algorithm, perl, bioinformatics

I have a script for parsing [BAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAM_(file_format)) files. The script's input thus is lines like

```
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:3:1101:24890:5616   99      22      16052014        150M
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:1:1110:21704:27345  99      22      16052044        150M
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:1:1217:2372:69519   163     22      16052044        150M
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:3:2123:8948:16779   99      22      16052044        150M
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:2:2213:2920:25534   147     22      16052054        146M4S
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:2:2206:5020:71717   83      22      16052055        145M5S
E00489:44:HNNVYCCXX:4:2206:12642:40829  99      22      16052056        144M6S
```

(The BAM file is actually run through `cut -f1-4,6` before input to this script so this is only a subset of fields.)

The first column is a kind of unique ID. The second is a bitwise flag. The third and fourth describe a chromosome and position in the human genome. The fifth is a [CIGAR string](http://bioinformatics.cvr.ac.uk/blog/tag/cigar-string/), which is mostly what the script parses.

---

I rarely use Perl, but it seems highly inefficient. It does work as intended, but it's slow. I'd like to speed it up and also make it more readable and easy-to-follow, if possible.

---

```
#!/bin/perl

#initialize hashes
my %softhash;
my %IDhash;
my $file1Name = $ARGV[0] . 'all_sc_positions.txt';
my $file2Name = $ARGV[0] . 'edge_sc_positions.txt';
open(my $fh_all, '>', $file1Name);
open(my $fh_edge, '>', $file2Name);

#for each line
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {

    #read in line and parse
    chomp($line);
    my @a = split("\t", $line);
    my $start = $a[3];
    my $cigar = $a[4];
    my @b = split(/[A-Z]/, $cigar);# keeps track of numbers
    my @c = split(/[0-9]*/, $cigar); #keeps track of letters
    my $loc = $start; #distance from start of read
    my $var_start;
    my $var_end;

    #loop over type of alignment in cigar string, build hashes of candidate locations
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#c; $i++) {

        #if there is softclipping or an indel, find the location and store in hash
        if ($c[$i] eq "S" || $c[$i] eq "I" || $c[$i] eq "D") {

            #find softclipping location
            if ($i == 1) {

                $var_start = $start - $b[0];
                $var_end = $start;

                if ($c[$i] eq "S") {

                    for (my $pos = $var_start; $pos < $var_end; $pos++) {
                        $softhash{$a[2]}{$pos}++;
                    }

                    $var_start = $var_end - 1;
                    $var_end = $var_start; 
                }

            } else {

                for (my $j = $i-2; $j >= 0; $j--) {# subtract 2 from i, because the first value from c will always be empty
                    $loc = $loc + $b[$j]; 
                }

                $var_start = $loc;
                $var_end = $loc + $b[($i-1)];

                if ($c[$i] eq "S") { 

                      for (my $pos=$var_start; $pos<$var_end; $pos++) {
                           $softhash{$a[2]}{$pos}++;
                      }

                      $var_end = $var_start;
                }
            }

            $IDhash{$a[2]}{$var_start}{$var_end}{$c[$i]}++;         
        }       
    }
}

#write out edge features
foreach my $key_chr (sort(keys %IDhash)) {

        foreach my $key_start (sort { $a <=> $b } (keys %{  $IDhash{$key_chr}  })) {

                foreach my $key_end (sort { $a <=> $b } (keys %{  $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}  })){

                    print $fh_edge "$key_chr\t$key_start\t$key_end\t";
                    my $sum = $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{I} + $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{D} + $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{S};
                    print $fh_edge "$sum,";

                    for my $l ('S','I','D') {

                    if (defined($IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{$l})) {
                         print $fh_edge  "$IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{$l},";
                    } else {
                        print $fh_edge "0,";
                    }
            }   

            print $fh_edge "\n";        
        }
    }
}

#write out "all" features
foreach my $key_chr (sort(keys %softhash)) {

        foreach my $key_pos (sort { $a <=> $b } (keys %{  $softhash{$key_chr}  })) {

             print $fh_all "$key_chr\t$key_pos\t";
             print $fh_all "$softhash{$key_chr}{$key_pos}\n";
        }
}
```

[Gist!](https://gist.github.com/jaLasser/4f01cf9166185d723ee9797d1389c676)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You said you rarely use Perl, and you inherited this code; do you at least understand how it works?

Comment: There are circumstances where reviewing inherited code is allowable: "I inherited this code, and I made this modification — what do you think?" However, if you are posting your predecessor's code, with no significant contribution of your own, and are asking for performance enhancements and behaviour changes, that's squarely off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @Phrancis I do!

Comment: @200_success yes, I've made many modifications--in fact, I added all the functionality relating to `softhash`.

Comment: @randoms Good, I hope you get great answers!

Comment: Can you please define "slow" and what kind of performance you're hoping to get?

Comment: @ChatterOne it sometimes takes several hours to run—I run it some input files `>10Gb`. I'd like to get the best performance possible.

Comment: StackExchange converts tabs to spaces, so the example input is no use for testing. Perhaps you could link a gist, pastebin, etc.

Comment: Also, if you can link a couple of large files (say one which takes about one minute and one which takes about 10 minutes) that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, what assumptions do you make about the contents of CIGAR strings? The only relevant constraint in the doc, AFAICT, is "*`S` may only have `H` operations between them and the ends of the CIGAR string*", but the treatment of `$loc` suggests that you make some stronger assumptions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yeah, I shouldn't have gone beyond that—that's the strongest assumption.  I linked a Gist above with a copy of the script and a 100,000 line input file, which takes about a minute to process. Unfortunately, given the sensitive nature of the data, I don't think I can provide much more than that.

Comment: Non-academic Perl developer here. I might write a long answer later, but up front: you should add `use strict` and `use warnings` to make sure you don't have silly mistakes in the code. `@a`, `@b` and so on are bad variable names. Call them what they are. Long names increase readability for you and future-you, but don't make the code slower. Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Cigar. Haven't investigated yet, but it might be a more correct implementation, though possibly slower. Can you include example output that you are _sure is correct_ for at least the small file? 1/2

Comment: You don't want to make changes to production code without knowing that your output is correct, and having the means to prove that. You should have some kind of tests for it. My suggestion would be to first move this code into a function, then add some unit tests for known formats, even if only a handful. Then use this when you make changes. Another thing to look at might be https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf to analyse the performance. 2/2

Comment: @simbabque thank you for the tips! and that's a very interesting library, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Non-code / very-high-level considerations.

The first thing you can do to speed up the performance would be to get a better computer. My computer is several years old, but it runs the unmodified code on the 100000-line example in less than one second, whereas you say it takes you a minute. (Of course, it's still worth remembering that better algorithms *amplify* the performance benefit of better hardware, so I will look at the hardware too).

---

My experience in bioinformatics is very limited, and I've never worked with this particular format before. I have only looked briefly at the docs. However, following your link to a description of the CIGAR string, and then another link from that page to https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf , I observe the statement

> S may only have H operations between them and the ends of the CIGAR string

However, 1368 lines of the 100000-line example violate that restriction. I suggest that you review the code to check that it doesn't rely on it, since you're the domain expert and have better understanding of what the codes mean than most if not all of us.

---

And I think it is worth pointing out with respect to your observation that

> I rarely use Perl, but it seems highly inefficient.

There's not much code here. Perhaps you should consider porting it to a language which you know better and is more efficient? (I would guess that Python run with PyPy or Cython would be faster, and Python knowledge seems to be common enough in your field that you wouldn't be creating problems for whoever later inherits it from you).

---

#### Code considerations

Possible bugs?

```
    my $loc = $start; #distance from start of read
    ...
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#c; $i++) {
        if ($c[$i] eq "S" || $c[$i] eq "I" || $c[$i] eq "D") {
            ...
            #find softclipping location
            if ($i == 1) {
                ...
            } else {
                for (my $j = $i-2; $j >= 0; $j--) {# subtract 2 from i, because the first value from c will always be empty
                    $loc = $loc + $b[$j]; 
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
        }       
    }
```

If I'm correctly interpreting things, shouldn't `$loc = $start` be just before the loop over `$j`? Otherwise a CIGAR string with several `I/D/S` will be double-counting some of the `$b[$j]`.

In addition, I really can't understand how `I` and `D` can be treated identically. Shouldn't one of them cause `$var_start` to go down?

---

**Note**: since the example too fast for me to get much useful profiling information out, this is based on common sense. Speed optimisation often defies common sense. I advise testing the suggestions one by one to see which work and which don't on large datasets.

The most obvious optimisation relates to `softhash`, and in particular the loop

> ```
>                     for (my $pos = $var_start; $pos < $var_end; $pos++) {
>                         $softhash{$a[2]}{$pos}++;
>                     }
> ```

If the ranges tend to be moderately wide then this is doing a lot of work and is ripe for optimisation. Specifically, you can replace that loop with

```
                    $softhash{$a[2]}{$var_start}++;
                    $softhash{$a[2]}{$var_end}--;
```

and then modify the output loop at the end to

```
foreach my $key_chr (sort(keys %softhash)) {
    my $accum = 0;
    my $prev_pos = -1;
    foreach my $key_pos (sort { $a <=> $b } (keys %{  $softhash{$key_chr}  })) {
         if ($accum > 0) {
             for (my $i = $prev_pos; $i < $key_pos; $i++) {
                 print $fh_all "$key_chr\t$i\t$accum\n";
             }
         }
         $accum += $softhash{$key_chr}{$key_pos};
         $prev_pos = $key_pos;
    }
```

The main processing should be much faster than before, and the output loop should be slightly faster because `(keys %{  $softhash{$key_chr}  })` has fewer items to sort.

---

If I'm right about `$loc` above, it might be worth eliminating the loop over `$j` and replacing it with an unconditional update of `$var_start` and `$var_end`. This probably won't help performance, but it might make the code more readable.

The other things I'd do for readability mainly relate to names. I think it would be helpful to pull out `$chromosome = $a[2]`; I wonder whether `$var_start` and `$var_end` might be better as `$range_start` and `$range_end`; and I'm pretty sure that the `key_` prefix doesn't convey much useful information. Reusing `$chromosome` instead of `$key_chr`, for example.

One other readability issue: I was puzzled by the loop `for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#c; $i++)` because it clearly runs one time too many. Either start the iteration at `1` or find some way to make the indexing start at `0`. If you implement the suggestion about updating the range unconditionally I think you cease to need to reference old values of `$b` and might be able to replace the loop with `while ($cigar =~ /([0-9]+)([A-Z])/g)` or something similar. (Not tested).

Comment: These are all great tips! I've implemented pretty much all of them—and in Python, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the advice from the other answer,
here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

---

All Perl code should include these lines at the top of the file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

With warnings enabled, I was immediately made aware that I was running the code
without supplying an argument on the command line that the code
was expecting.

If the argument is meant to be optional, the code should first
check if any was provided:

```
my $file1Name = 'all_sc_positions.txt';
my $file2Name = 'edge_sc_positions.txt';
if (@ARGV) {
    my $prefix = shift;
    $file1Name = $prefix . $file1Name;
    $file2Name = $prefix . $file2Name;
}
```

The code should have usage documentation.  For example, you could add
a comment block at the top describing:

- Summary of what the code does
- What it expects as input: BAM file, optional output file name prefix
- Creates 2 files in current directory

It is more conventional to omit the `STDIN` file handle when reading
input.  Change:

```
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
```

to:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
```

---

Since `foreach` is identical to `for`, and you already use `for`
elsewhere in the code, you should just use `for` everywhere.

---

There is inconsistent indentation inside this `for` loop:

```
for my $l ('S','I','D') {
```

[perltidy](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Tidy/view/bin/perltidy)
can be used to automatically apply consistent formatting to your code.

---

This type of `for` loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#c; $i++) {
```

is more simply written with the range operator (`..`) as:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#c) {
```

This is considered more "Perlish".

The same for:

```
for my $pos ($var_start .. $var_end) {
```

---

Simplify:

```
$loc = $loc + $b[$j];
```

using the `+=` assignment operator as:

```
$loc += $b[$j];
```

---

It is customary to omit parentheses with built-in functions.
You did so with `keys` in the line below:

```
foreach my $key_chr (sort(keys %IDhash)) {
```

You can do the same with `sort`:

```
for my $key_chr (sort keys %IDhash) {
```

---

Using the list constructor, `qw`, eliminates the need for all the quotes
and commas in the line:

```
for my $l ('S','I','D') {
```

Also, `$l` is not very descriptive.  Perhaps `$lett` is better:

```
for my $lett (qw(S I D)) {
```

---

You should check the success of `open` calls and `die` with
the error message [$!](https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$!)

```
open my $fh_all, '>', $file1Name or die "$file1Name $!";
```

---

Split the really long line up into a few lines so it is easier to understand:

```
my $sum = $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{I}
        + $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{D}
        + $IDhash{$key_chr}{$key_start}{$key_end}{S};
```